# How to draw a line in the corner cell in crosstab

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I need a line in the corner cell of a crosstab. For example:

[image: crosstab]

How can the reporting engine draw the red line in the picture and write colors and fruits to the respective places?

Comment: What have you tried? What does the JRXML look like? What happened when you dragged the crosstab element onto the report? What results did you get? What were you expecting? How have you wired the data -- are you using a SQL statement or Java objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Line element from the Palette. In JasperSoft Studio:

[image: Line]

If using iReport:

[image: Line]

Drag it onto the band, resize it, then move it over the crosstab's corner:

[image: Crosstab with Line]

Comment: @SamiŞimşekli: Please ask new questions, rather than leaving new questions in comments. Don't forget to accept answers by clicking the check mark, if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. My main question contains the last thing I have asked in the comment. "How can the reporting engine draw the red line in the picture 'and write colors and fruits to the respective places'?" So, why do you answer only the line part of it. I can change the question but still i need to write like that.